# toast msg went crazy for my checkbox validation

Tags: java, android, checkbox

I want to create a validation for the checkbox. For example, if the provider does not check one of the checkboxes, it will issue a Toast msg, "Please tick at least one of your selections."

My interface:-

[image]

My coding for validation method:-

```
else if(!(cbBM.isChecked()) || !(cbBI.isChecked()) || !(cbMath.isChecked()) || !(cbSc.isChecked()))
    {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please tick at least one of your selections.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

My coding for checkbox:-

```
cbBM = view.findViewById(R.id.bm);
    cbBM.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                     boolean isChecked)
        {
            if (isChecked) {
                //DO NOTHING
            }

            else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please tick at least one of your selections.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

The problem I faced was, the toast message **always display** if I did not tick the "Bahasa Melayu" option.

Comment: Just put your *!* inside bracket like if((!cbBM.isChecked()) || (!cbBI.isChecked())){} and test it.

Comment: @BhoomikaPatel Still cannot ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `&&` (logical AND) operator instead of `||` (logical OR).  
With the `||` operator if any of the checkboxes is unchecked you will see the toast.  
Try this:

```
if(!cbBM.isChecked() && !cbBI.isChecked() && !cbMath.isChecked() && !cbSc.isChecked())
```

if you want to use the listener, modify it like this:

```
cbBM = view.findViewById(R.id.bm);
    cbBM.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                     boolean isChecked)
        {
            checkNoSelection()
        }
    });
```

and create 3 more listeners for the other 3 checkboxes like the one above.

This is the `checkNoSelection()` method:

```
private void checkNoSelection() {
    if(!cbBM.isChecked() && !cbBI.isChecked() && !cbMath.isChecked() && !cbSc.isChecked()) {
           Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please tick at least one of your selections.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Still cannot. I have to tick on Bahasa Melayu, then the toast did not display.... Example, if I choose one option except Bahasa Melayu, it will continue toast the message.

Comment: @Daisy Did you make all the changes? See my edited code.

Comment: Why do you use the `setOnCheckedChangeListener` for `cbBM`? If you do then the you should check `if(!cbBM.isChecked() && !cbBI.isChecked() && !cbMath.isChecked() && !cbSc.isChecked())` otherwise the toast will be displayed every time you uncheck `cbBM`.

Comment: @Daisy please see my answer, hope helpful.

Comment: @Daisy sorry, my codes is wrong, i will modify it soon

Comment: Then forpas... Should I use this coding ---> if(!cbBM.isChecked() && !cbBI.isChecked() && !cbMath.isChecked() && !cbSc.isChecked())

Comment: This code can guarantee that if **all** the 4 checkboxes are **not** checked then the toast will appear

Comment: You will not see the toast if any checkbox is checked

Answer (score 0):

Notice when first express is true, the remain expressions are not checked. so if Bahasa Melayu is not ticked ,below logic express is always equal true, so toast message always displays.

```
 !(cbBM.isChecked()) || !(cbBI.isChecked()) || !(cbMath.isChecked()) || !(cbSc.isChecked())
```

You could try this:

```
  private boolean showHint = true;
  if(cbBM.isChecked()) showHint = false;
  if(cbBI.isChecked()) showHint = false;
  if(cbMath.isChecked()) showHint = false;
  if(cbSc.isChecked()) showHint = false;
  if(showHint == true){
     Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please tick at least one of your selections.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
```

Edited:
     add above codes in other place, may be in `submit` button click listener, and change `showHint` to class field.